# Remove digits from end of string

Tags: bash, awk, grep, gnuwin32

I want to remove digits from end of a string.

Example:

```
 string123
 example545
```

Output:

```
string
example
```

Comment: Does any of the below answer ur question?

Comment: Yes I've ticked the one that does :), sorry I was afk

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted.  Some people here are certainly pretentious.

Comment: @HH probably because it looks a lot like a homework question, with no apparent effort made (or at least demonstrated) to find the answer. They get cranky about that.

Of course now I'm trying to do something similar, and my search led me here 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you have no other digits anywhere else in the string you can do:

```
echo string123 | sed 's/[0-9]//g'
string
```

And only the end of the string:

```
echo S1tring123 | sed 's/[0-9]\+$//'
S1tring
```

Where `$` indicates the end of the line.

Comment: what if string contains say " S1tring123 " I wish to only remove the ending digits, so remove digits up until alpha type of thing

Comment: Well it is important in the first one as that would remove only the first digit :)

Answer (score 13):

Without external tools, just [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and extended globbing:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ var=string123
$ echo "${var%%+([[:digit:]])}"
string
$ var=example545
$ echo "${var%%+([[:digit:]])}"
example
```

The `+(pattern)` extended glob pattern is "one or more of this", so `+([[:digit:]])` is "one or more digits".

The `${var%%pattern}` expansion means "remove the longest possible match of *`pattern`* from the end of `var`.

Comment: How do you disable the extglob again?

Comment: @Hubert `shopt -u extglob`

Answer (score 2):

With grep

```
echo S1tring123 | grep -o '.*[^0-9]'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]+$/,"")}1' file

string
example
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to fully understand your requirements, but try:

```
sed 's/[0-9]*\([^[:alnum:]]*\)$/\1/' file
```

or perhaps:

```
sed 's/[0-9]*\([^0-9]*\)$/\1/' file
```